# Putting GPS current location and pin annotations on a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, annotations, uiimageview, gps, location

I am making an iPhone app for a local college. I am currently trying to take a drawn map of the campus and put pin annotations on it. I also want to be able to show the users current location on this map image. Right now I just have a UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView. It can currently scroll and zoom in/out. How would I go about accomplishing this? I have searched everywhere for an answer and can't seem to find a solution (or have overlooked it). Am I going in the right direction? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to come up with a function to translate latitude and longitude into pixel offsets in the image. Assuming the campus is relatively small compared to the Earth (so you can ignore the planet's curvature), this should be a simple matter of determining the coordinates of the four corners of the image and interpolating.

Comment: Ok. That doesn't seem so bad. I guess I would have to make my own pin annotation and callout animations? Is there a method for putting something on an image at a particular pixel?

Comment: I want it to function like the campus map in the iTCU app.

Comment: Easiest would probably be to just add your pin views as subviews of the UIImageView holding the map. I have no idea what the iTCU app is.